# How did the ZX80 store both a useful program and screen memory?

Tags: memory, zx81, zx80

I have a vague recollection from my earliest days that the ZX80 only shipped with 1K of RAM.

If this RAM was used to store both the program *and* the contents of the 32x24 screen, wouldn't that mean only about 256 bytes were available for programming?

Or was there some trick used for video memory, such as a separate section of memory dedicated to the screen, apart from the advertised 1K RAM?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Both the ZX80 and the ZX81 had a variable-size display file (DFILE). They didn't store the complete screen contents, but rather only the characters per line up to a terminating newline.  This *collapsed DFILE* is activated when the ZX detects less than 3 1/4kB of memory on startup. A collapsed DFILE can thus be as small as 24+1 bytes (initial HALT, 24 NEWLINEs, or HALT instructions) for an empty screen.

Because ZX-80 and ZX-81 "execute" the DFILE in the display output routine as NOPs, the terminating newline character has to be the opcode of a HALT instruction (76h). This stops the CPU fetching bytes from the DFILE and makes it internally execute NOPs until interrupted (which happens at the end of each scanline, 8 times per character line). The video hardware simply generates white space pixels for the rest of the line.

This results in much less screen memory used than the 768 bytes you would otherwise need for a full screen, at least if you did not fill the complete lines with 32 characters.

[Here](http://www.searle.wales/zx80/zx80ScopePics.html) is a detailed description of how this works (on Grant Searle's great Z80 pages).

Comment: Wow, Grant has *way* too much time on his hands :-) That's an impressive set of pages, I especially liked the "how to build your own complete zx80/zx81/ace" stuff. The execution of the display file is rather bizarre ...

Comment: @paxdiablo execution of the display file is clever: why put an extra counter into the budget machine when you can just reuse the one that's right there inside the CPU?

Comment: @paxdiablo *bizarre* is not the proper term, IMHO. *Ingenious* fits it better.

Comment: @Tommy Actually, it's at least three counters that run through the DFILE on the CPU: (1) the address lines that run over the DFILE on an instruction fetch (2) The R register that triggers the interrupt to get the Z80 out of HALT after each scanline, and (3) the IX register that addresses the ROM character. BTW It gets even more ingenious when you look how easy you can tweak the ZX-81 display routine to implement pixel-addressable Hi-res graphics in software only.

Comment: @tofro yeah, I've written one of only two emulators that score 100% timing accuracy to a real ZX81, I was just trying to keep it simple by sticking to the thing already being discussed. I don't think IX is involved though — probably you meant I, which contributes the top 8 bits of the refresh address and therefore the top 7 bits of the character lookup address? Nowhere near as good as Grant Searle's documentation, but my hardware summary is at https://github.com/TomHarte/CLK/wiki/The-ZX80-and-ZX81

Comment: The Atari 2600 Basic Programming cartridge manages to go one better than this--it generates a line of text from the tokenized source, then displays it, generates another line of text using the same buffer, displays that, etc.thus avoiding any duplication between memory used to store a tokenized program and memory used to display it as text.

Comment: @supercat but then again, re: "better", a program running on the ZX80 and ZX81 can output anything it wants over the whole screen, subject to available memory, whereas I think the Atari BASIC offers only two lines out of twelve for your own output? Which, admittedly, is still a superhuman feat with only 128 bytes of RAM.

Comment: @Tommy: The total number of characters, including newlines, that can be output would be 64 minus the number of bytes used for other purposes.  If more lines are output than will fit on the screen the remainder will not be displayed (there is no provision for scrolling, but one could maximize the number of display lines by turning off all the other windows).  I don't think this trick would work on the ZX81 since much of the scan-line timing is hardware-controlled.  Not sure about the ZX80.  I'm not sure how many blank scan lines would generally be needed for each line of program.

Comment: @Tommy: If programs were stored in MS-basic style, I'd guess something like `LD A,(HL) / INC HL / INC A / JP PO,x / MOV (DE),A / INC E / JP NZ,LP` would be typical for bytes that aren't parts of tokens.  7+6+4+10+7+4+10 -- 48 cycles out of 256 per line, so 8 blank scan lines per each displayed line of program might be workable.  Losing half of screen real estate might be annoying, but avoiding the need for a screen buffer might make it worthwhile, esp. if there wouldn't be enough memory for more than 12 lines of program anyway.

Comment: @tofro, don't get me wrong, I didn't mean "bizarre" in a bad way, just massively out of the ordinary (like extraordinary). I *am* impressed with the way it was done, in a way I haven't been since I first saw the Woz/Wig RWTS disk I/O code.

Comment: Rather inconveniently, the `SCROLL` command always created a blank line 21 even when you had enough memory to default to a full DFILE, so anyone doing serious scrolling wrote a quick memory copy in machine code to scroll instead.

Comment: The ZGrass and BASIC for the Bally was even crazier. They had four colors per pixel, so they set two of the colors the same as the other two and then put one bit of color and one bit of code in every screen location, with the high bit having no effect because the colors were the same.

Comment: tofro, I see Grant has Z80 pages (amongst a great deal of other stuff I intend to read now that you've uncovered them for me) but I wonder whether this answer should actually be changed to read "Grant Searle's great Z***X***80 pages" since it (and the link) are specifically for the ZX80 rather than the Z80 in general. Normally, I'd just edit the answer but I don't want to step on your toes.

Comment: @paxdiablo Grant's great home page provides a plethora of information on computers, some (minor) part actually covering the ZX80/81 and the very similar Jupiter Ace, but the majority really is on CP/M / Z80 and other retro CPUs.

Answer (score -1):

It did not (at least not without ugly tricks). In addition to tofro's answer, a simple program at ZX-81 looking something like this (writing from memory):

```
10 FOR Y=1 TO 24
20 FOR X=1 TO 32
30 PRINT AT Y,X;"X"
40 NEXT X
50 NEXT Y
```

... was enough to achieve Out-of-memory error, because there was not enough room in memory for this measly program, system variables and a full display.

Comment: Seems to be not true. At least not on ZX80 on this emulator http://nocanvas.zame-dev.org/0004/

Comment: @UncleBod are you able to show the code you ran? The ZX 80 does not have an `AT`, like the ZX Spectrum does and like Edheldil's code shows.

Comment: I guess just `PRINT "X";` would achieve what the author is trying to communicate?

Comment: @wilson As above, except only PRINT "X"; instead of PRINT AT (Which ZX80 doesn't have).  The program size might differ 4-5 bytes, not more. And really, to cram as much as possible into a computer was a sport in those days. Search for ZX81 1K Chess....

Comment: ZX81 1K Chess only used 8 lines of the display for the same reason discussed here. 

I would guess the ZX80 emulator you used was set up to have expanded RAM. Sinclair sold a 3K RAM pack for it, but the initial machine came with only 1K. It could not store a full screen of characters.

Comment: I remember on my old 1K ZX80, as I typed in more and more program, it would seem to lose more and more of it from the end, "eating" its way from the bottom of the screen upwards. Presumably because the DFILE had to be sacrificed for the actual program. And ISTR the 3K expansion pack (when I finally got some money together as a poor student) was *very* flaky, prone to reboot as the slightest tremor. I'm pretty certain it was a good idea to leave the room if you had to cough  :-)